# AppendTo doesn't update when interacting with PopupMenu

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dynamic, button

I'm trying to `ListPlot` a list calculated by the `Button` called "Plot" with `PopupMenu` linked to `ListPlot` to control the temperature units of displayed data, for example: if  `"DegreesCelsius" -> "C"` is selected from the list then `ListPlot` should show plotted curve in `"DegreesCelsius"` and the same goes for `"DegreesFahrenheit"`. `AppendTo` is used here to `ListPlot` new list every time the input of `InputField`  is changed and `Button` is pressed by appending it to the old one.

My Problem is that the temperature units of the plotted curves don't change when selecting different values from `PopupMenu`. `AppendTo` doesn't update accordingly. I can see that `popupSelection` variable changes when interacting with `PopupMenu` but `plotData` variable only changes when `Button` is pressed, using current `PopupMenu` selection.

If I remove `AppendTo` from `Button` and include `dataSet4:=Transpose[...]` instead, as well as keeping it in `Initialization` everything works as I wanted. I tried to make several changes by shifting things around but nothing helped.

Please Help!

The example below demonstrates the issue.

```
  DynamicModule[{},
     inputList = {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}};
     Dynamic@Column[{
        InputField[Dynamic[inputData]],
        Dynamic@Button["Plot",
          dataSet1 = Map[Norm, Differences[inputList]];
          dataSet2 = Exp[-N[Pi]*0.345*5*dataSet1/(10*2000)];
          dataSet3 = FoldList[10 + (#1 - 10)*#2 &, inputData, dataSet2];
          AppendTo[plotData, dataSet4]],
     Spacer[5],
            PopupMenu[Dynamic[popupSelection], {"DegreesCelsius" -> "C", "DegreesFahrenheit" -> "F"}],
            ListPlot[plotData, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}, Frame -> True]}],
         Initialization :> (
           popupSelection = "DegreesCelsius";
           inputData = 0;
           plotData = {};
           dataSet3 = {0};
           dataSet4 := Transpose[{inputList[[All, 1]], QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[QuantityArray[dataSet3, "DegreesCelsius"], popupSelection]}];),
         SynchronousInitialization -> False]
```

**Cross-posted on** [**Wolfram Community**](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1632919?p_p_auth=5ZX57ViH)

Comment: The variable `popupSelection` only influences what `dataSet4` evaluates to when the button is clicked and `dataSet4` in turn is only appended to `plotData`. How is `popupSelection` then supposed to influence all the values that were already stored in `plotData`?. You'd need to recalculate all elements in `plotData` for this to work. Is it not easier to just keep the data as quantities and only convert them right before plotting?

Comment: I'm new to Mathematica and I'm not sure what you mean by that. How to convert data just before plotting if plotted data is of the format {{a, b}, {c, d},...} and only 1 column must be converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I suggested in my comment, it's probably easier to just keep the units around until you plot them. Here's a suggestion:

```
DynamicModule[{initQ = False},
 inputList = {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}};
 Dynamic[If[TrueQ[initQ], 
   Column[{InputField[Dynamic[inputData]], 
     Dynamic@Button["Plot", 
       dataSet1 = Map[Norm, Differences[inputList]];
       dataSet2 = Exp[-N[Pi]*0.345*5*dataSet1/(10*2000)];
       dataSet3 = FoldList[10 + (#1 - 10)*#2 &, inputData, dataSet2];
       AppendTo[plotData, dataSet4]], Spacer[5], 
     PopupMenu[
      Dynamic[popupSelection], {"DegreesCelsius" -> "C", 
       "DegreesFahrenheit" -> "F"}],
     ListPlot[
      Map[
       QuantityMagnitude[#, {"DimensionlessUnit", popupSelection}] &,
       plotData
       ],
      Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}, Frame -> True
      ]}],
   ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace"]
   ]
  ],
 Initialization :> (popupSelection = "DegreesCelsius";
   inputData = 0;
   plotData = {};
   dataSet3 = {0};
   dataSet4 := QuantityArray[
     Transpose[{
       inputList[[All, 1]],
       dataSet3
       }],
     {"DimensionlessUnit", "DegreesCelsius"}
     ];
   initQ = True
   ),
 SynchronousInitialization -> False
]
```

Comment: It works great. Thanks for your help